# Communicating between Views

Tags: wpf

My WPF app has two views and each view has its own view model. One view shows all the customer names on the left side. The second view shows the list of items ordered by the selected customer(on the first view) on the right side. The data in the second view should be changed automatically based on my selection on the first view(customer names view). Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at using a framework such as Prism or MVVMLight or etc. They usually provide some way for ViewModels to communicate to each other. Prism, for example, has the `IEventAggregator` interface (and supporting class). This allows one ViewModel to "publish" notifications and another to "subscribe" to notifications. The publisher doesn't care who is subscribed, if any ViewModel is. The subscriber doesn't care who is publishing. This allows the ViewModels to remain completely decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called 'Master-Detail' binding.  The general idea is that the left hand Customer-List view (the master view) will be bound to a ViewModel comprising a list of CustomerViewModels, and a selected CustomerViewModel.  Changing the selected item in your customer list will update the selected CustomerViewModel in the ViewModel.  Each of the CustomerViewModel should have a collection of PurchaseViewModels which detail that customer's orders.  The right hand side view (the detail view) should set it's DataContext to the selected CustomerViewModel, and use the list of purchases.

Here is an eerily well-suited project to use as an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application